# C# Filtering Entities by previous entity

Tags: c#, filter, entity

Why can I filter an entity on one line, but not use the same entity to filter on another line.

For example, this works

```
    IEnumerable<MyDataEntity> allRecords = _testRepository.Entity.ByCreatedYear(year);
    IEnumerable<MyDataEntity> allRecords1 = _testRepository.Entity.ByCreatedYear(year).ByEnding123();
```

But this does not work

```
        IEnumerable<MyDataEntity> allRecords = _testRepository.Entity.ByCreatedYear(year);
        IEnumerable<MyDataEntity> allRecords1 = allRecords.ByEnding123();
```

I want to search on the previous result so I don't have to query the database again.

Comment: Because whoever wrote your methods `ByEnding123` and `ByCreatedYear` did not design them that way

Comment: Because `ByEnding123` is not a member of `IEnumerable`??